# Disabling Strict Standards Errors in WordPress 3.7 with PHP 5.4

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, httpd.conf, osx-mavericks

I am trying to disable STRICT Error reporting in WordPress 3.7 via my php.ini file after updating my computer to OS X 10.9. I am running PHP Version 5.4.17, the one that ships with Mavericks.

In my wp-config.php file, I have enabled `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` which was on a working fine before upgrading my OS and as a result, PHP.

In the php.ini file, I have tried setting error_reporting to:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

or

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

or

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

even

```
error_reporting = 0
```

But the errors still appear.

display_errors is set to Off:

```
display_errors = Off
```

After each change to the file, I am restarting apache and httpd with these two commands:

```
httpd -k restart
apachectl restart
```

The php.ini file I am editing is the same one being pointed to in phpinfo() AND just to make sure changes are going through, I have been editing the error_prepend_string value:

```
error_prepend_string = "<span style='color: #ff0000'>ERROR: "
```

and those changes are coming through in the error.

Any thoughts on how to debug this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Inside the phpinfo() what's the value of error_reporting?

Comment: `phpinfo()` will also show the actual local and master runtime values for `error_reporting` and `display_errors` in the **Core** section, please share what they show.

Comment: @Jack The **Local Value** is '32767'. The **Master Value** is 'no value'.

Comment: I think its.. error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT if my memory serves me correctly

Comment: Also, `error_reporting(0);` isn't going to work of course in php.ini, that should be `error_reporting = 0`. But `32767` most certainly includes E_STRICT (2048). Either you're not editing the correct php config file, or your code resets the value somewhere before the `phpinfo()` call.

Comment: Just out of curiosity then, what's the value of `display_errors` inside the phpinfo() page?

Comment: @Jack for display_errors, Local Value 'On' Master Value 'Off'

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes 
It looks like as of WP 3.6, WP_DEBUG enforces strict — however, I was running 3.6 before upgrading to Mavericks & PHP 5.4, and I was not getting these errors.

Comment: PHP 5.4 introduced a lot of new strict warnings, that's the real issue - has nothing to do with Maverick or OSX of course. What's happening is that Wordpress (being an enormous pile of crap) enforces `error_reporting` values internally somewhere. Run `grep -r error_reporting *` in the webroot to find out where.

Comment: WP 3.7 is out :). and error reporting in wp is in wp-config.php

Comment: And I've seen 3.6 installs getting frequently hacked since about 6 weeks, so yeah I'd definitely upgrade if you really insist on using the most fundamentally insecure CMS in the history of web development.

Comment: @xlordt hmm, upgrading to 3.7 didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120006) helps.

Answer (score 18):

In Wordpress 3.7, the function `wp_debug_mode` (defined in `wp-includes/load.php`, and called from `wp-setings.php`) sets `error_reporting( E_ALL )`.

Since `wp-settings.php` is itself loaded at the end of `wp-config.php`, you cannot change this setting from `wp-config.php` (or rather, you can, but it will be overridden).

A solution is to create a "Must Use plugin", that is to say a .php file located in the `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` folder containing :

```
<?php
if (WP_DEBUG && WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY) 
{
   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
}
```

Comment: This works partially, because some error happen before functions.php gets loaded. +1 for the idea however :)

Comment: I didn't see any errors in my (limited) testing, though I suppose it can happen when loading plugins. Looking at [Wordpress load order](http://www.rarst.net/images/wordpress_core_load.png), maybe a solution is to create a very simple plugin to set error_reporting, making sure it is loaded before any other plugin (by default they are loaded in alphabetical order).

Comment: For best results, use the solution provided by adelval, but put it in a .php file such as: `/wp-content/mu-plugins/errorreporting.php`. "mu" stands for "must-use" and will be loaded before the theme and plugins, but after the error reporting has been set. You don't have to activate it, either, since they are "must-use".

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre for the edit, it improves the answer by incorporating the  comment by RadGH

Comment: This didnt help me either as the deprecated error message is done before it even gets to the mu-plugin.

In my case the problem is in wp-db.php, where the error is:
Deprecated: mysql_connect()

Comment: THIS! - Thank you so much for it

Answer (score 0):

I found that only

```
error_reporting = off
```

works, as STRICT errors have become part of ALL as of PHP 5.4 which is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If you set WP_DEBUG to 'false' in wp-config.php file. These do not affect your website.

Bot the problem is that above does not work sometime.
That can happen on cheap/shared hostings that force displaying PHP ERRORS, warnings and notices.
In that case, you can remove this line from your wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

and place this:

```
ini_set('log_errors','On');
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

in my case its working.